# Combining JavaCV and openCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I have the following problem: 
I have an Android application which uses native OpenCV code. In a first step, the frames which were edited by OpenCV came from the camera. Then they were processed and drawn on the display.

However, my requirements now have changed. The frames which have to be edited come from a video file stored on the SD card. They must be processed by the openCV code and then stored in a new video file.

After reading some a lot of stuff, I recognized that Android has no built-in stuff for correctly reading a video file frame by frame and allowing to process the frames while doing so. On a computer OpenCV has the VideoCapture function. But this does not work on Android as openCV has no ffmpeg that comes with it.

After reading more stuff, I found that JavaCV comes with an FFMPEGFrameGrabber and also an FFMPEGFrameRecorder. So, I implemented everything which now allows me to grab single frames from a video, obtain an IplImage frame and store this frame in a new video.

Now the problem:
During obtaining and storing the IplImage frame must be processed using the original OpenCV code as it is not feasible to port the complete code to JavaCV.

So in a first place I wrote a small test JNI function which gets the address of a MAT object and draws a small circle on it.

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_de_vion_postprocessing_step2_EyeTracking_editFrame(
    JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong thiz, jlong addrRgba) {
//Convert the mat addresses into the objects
Mat& rgbFrame = *(Mat*) addrRgba;

Point2i scaledSmoothPoint(100,100);
circle(rgbFrame, scaledSmoothPoint, 20, YELLOW, -1);
}
```

As I read that IplImage extends CvArr I just call the function within in my code as follows:

```
captured_frame = grabber.grab();
if (captured_frame == null) {
    // no new frames
    break;
}
editFrame(captured_frame .address());
```

However, I now get the following error:

```
06-12 18:58:23.135: E/cv::error()(6498): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (cn <= 4) in
                    void cv::scalarToRawData(const Scalar&, void*, int, int), file 
                    /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 845
06-12 18:58:23.135: A/libc(6498): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00001962 (code=-6),
                    thread 6526 (AsyncTask #1)
```

Finally, me question:
How can I process the IplImage frame using nativeOpenCV and finally store this IplImage  frame then in the video recorder.

I am also open to new Ideas which do not necessarily require JavaCV as long as I do not have to write the FrameGrabber and FrameRecorder my self.

Best regards,
André

Comment: I know that. This is the reason why I do not use JavaCV for image processing. I only usw the JavaCV FFmeg Grabber and Recorder as OpenCV does not provide such functionality for Android.

Answer (score 3):

Intel released a new tool called INDE, which contains a component called INDE Media Pack. This is however using Java. Media pack takes the Android media framework and has done some heavy encapsulating of certain features and added a few things to make Video/Audio/Image processing very simple. You can download from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inde)

Here is how you can do video capture starting at a particular frame and ending at a frame(not complete code, just to give you an idea) using INDE. You will find lot of sample code once you download  the tool

```
    public void start(String videoPath) throws IOException
    {
        if (isStarted())
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(TAG + " already started!");
        }

        capturer = new GLCapture(new AndroidMediaObjectFactory());

        capturer.setTargetFile(videoPath);
        capturer.setTargetVideoFormat(videoFormat);

        capturer.start();

        isStarted = true;
        isConfigured = false;
        framesCaptured = 0;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look into it later. Sounds really good.